# Python - Recursion: duplicate int, duplicate int in a list, duplicate int in a nested list

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I'm learning recursion and I can't quite figure out why this isn't working.

**What it should do:**

```
>>> copy(1)
[1, 1]
>>> copy([1, 2])
[1, 1, 2, 2]
>>> copy([1, [2, 3]]) 
[1, 1, [2, 2, 3, 3]]
```

So basically the code should just duplicate each integer. Note: The position in the list and the format (if it is a nested list) does not change, all this code does is insert a duplicate int beside each int in the list.

**Code:**

```
def copy(nested_list):
    new_list = []

    #if list is empty
    if isinstance(nested_list, list) and len(nested_list) == 0:
        return new_list

    # if it's only an int
    elif isinstance(nested_list, int):
        new_list.append(nested_list)
        new_list.append(nested_list)

    else:
        # if list is a list
        if isinstance(nested_list, list):
            for num in range(len(nested_list)):
                if isinstance(nested_list[num], int):
                    new_list.append(nested_list[num])
                    new_list.append(nested_list[num])
                elif isinstance(nested_list[num], list):
                    copy(nested_list[num])
                else:
                    pass

    return new_list
```

It works for most of the examples, except the last one.

What it keeps giving back for the last example:

```
Expected:
    [1, 1, [2, 2, 3, 3]]
Got:
    [1, 1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this one!

```
def copy(nested_list):
    new_list = []

    #if list is empty
    if isinstance(nested_list, list) and len(nested_list) == 0:
        return new_list

    # if it's only an int
    elif isinstance(nested_list, int):
            new_list.append(nested_list)
            new_list.append(nested_list)

    else:
        # if list is a list
        if isinstance(nested_list, list):
            for num in range(len(nested_list)):
                if isinstance(nested_list[num], int):
                    new_list.append(nested_list[num])
                    new_list.append(nested_list[num])
                elif isinstance(nested_list[num], list):
                    tempList = copy(nested_list[num])
                    new_list.append(tempList)
                else:
                    pass

    return new_list

print(copy([1, [2, 3]]))
```

Comment: ahh yes, I should handled the result of the recursive call. Good catch, thank you!

Comment: Please mention in your answer what mistake OP made, and why your code works.

Comment: @rakeb.mazharul i will keep this in my mind. I appreciate your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Your `copy` function is recursive, but you ignore the result of the recursive call to `copy` entirely:

```
elif isinstance(nested_list[num], list):
    copy(nested_list[num])
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You probably want to append the items returned by your call to `copy` to the end of `new_list`:

```
new_list.append(copy(nested_list[num]))
```

You can also simplify it a little:

```
def copy(nested_list):
    if isinstance(nested_list, int):
        return copy([nested_list])

    result = []

    for elem in nested_list:
        if isinstance(elem, int):
            result.append(elem)
            result.append(elem)
        else:
            result.append(copy(elem))

    return result
```

Comment: that works, however, i think you meant to put .append and not extend, extend would return something like [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], but i need [1, 1, [2, 2, 3, 3]]

Answer (score 1):

Here's another implementation!

```
def copy(items):
    if isinstance(items, int):
        return [items, items]

    result = []
    for element in items:
        if isinstance(element, int):
            result.extend(copy(element))
        else:
            result.append(copy(element))
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick to recursion is to solve the most basic case and call itself to solve a (now) smaller problem:

```
def repeat_int(seq_or_int, nested=False):
    try:
        first, *rest = seq_or_int
    except TypeError:  # got int
        return [seq_or_int] * 2  # repeat int
    except ValueError:  # empty
        result = []
    else:
        result = repeat_int(first, nested=True) + repeat_int(rest)
    return [result] if nested else result  # nest in a list if necessary
```

Example:

```
>>> repeat_int(1)
[1, 1]
>>> repeat_int([1, 2])
[1, 1, 2, 2]
>>> repeat_int([1, [2, 3]])
[1, 1, [2, 2, 3, 3]]
```

There are two basic cases here:

- the input is not an iterable (a scalar such as `int`)—return the repeated input in a list
- the input is empty—return an empty list.

[The Python 3 iterable unpacking syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/#rationale) chops off the first item in the input collection:

```
first, *rest = seq_or_int
```

To get the result for the rest of the collection, the recursive call is made with (now) smaller list: `repeat_int(rest)`.

All that is left is to deal with the first item that is the same as the input may be a collection too. To preserve the structure, the `nested` indicator is passed and if it is set then the result list is wrapped in another list.